# How do I hide the scrollbar for inner scrolling in Chrome?

Tags: css, scrollbar

This hides the scrollbar on Safari, but not on Chrome, why?

```css
.inner-scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar,
.inner-scrolling::-chrome-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Anyway, I did set up inner scrolling like this:

```css
.inner-scrolling {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.inner-scrolling::-webkit-scrollbar{
width: 0;
}
```

By applying width 0 to scrollbar, will hide scrollbar.

and for moz we can add `scrollbar-width: none;`